# SwiftUI Image clipsToBounds

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Experimenting with SwiftUI (Xcode 11.0 beta 2), I try to fill a View with an image :

```
Image("large")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
    .border(Color.black)
```

This renders like so :

[image: No clipping]

I would like to apply something similar to [`UIView.clipsToBounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds) so the image is clipped and the parts outside of the box are not visible.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the `.clipped()` modifier, which results in an effect similar to `UIView.clipsToBounds`:

```
Image("large")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
    .border(Color.black)
    .clipped() // Equal to clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Please note that clipped MUST follow the frame not precede it otherwise it won’t work!

Comment: IMPORTANT: This worked great for me, visually. I found an issue where if the clipped region of the image overlaps a button, that button will NOT work. Even though it looks perfect, the button will not receive the touches that it should. To get around that I had to manually clip the image (using UIKit) to a specific CGSize BEFORE sending it to the SwiftUI Image's init(uiImage:). I hope this helps someone in my situation! And if anyone has a better way to handle this PLEASE let me know.

Comment: @SeanRobinson159 I just got the same problem. I set the frame alignment to .top as my button was at the top so the image overlaps things at the bottom where nothing were to worry about. But still very not optimal... :/

Comment: You can use a ZStack to make sure the button is on top.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue where the Image in the content of an AsyncImage was blocking a Picker from detecting input.  I tried various clipping and contentShape options but they did not work.  I "fixed" it by setting the .zIndex(1) on the Picker. Pretty crappy solution but it worked.

Comment: @SeanRobinson159 please see my response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71007413/4383631  It might help you.

Comment: For the hit zone being hidden, do not forget to set the appropriate contentShape(), which actually solves that particular issue!

Answer (score 32):

```
Image("large")
   .resizable()
   .clipShape(Circle())
   .frame(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
   .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white,lineWidth:4).shadow(radius: 10))
```

[image: OutPut]

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but the `clipShape` is definitely cool !

Answer (score 27):

```
Image("large")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
+   .contentShape(Rectangle())
+   .clipped()
    .border(Color.black)
```

This helped me fixing the issue by image overlapping a button. contentShape() was used to clip hit-testing area.
clipped() is clipping the contents inside the view's bounds(as others mentioned).

Comment: For this I searched over an hour. Thank you so much! .contentShape() was what I needed.

Comment: yeah! Exactly, thanks!

Comment: Omg, I've spent three days finding this answer, thank you!

Answer (score -4):

```
Use GeometryReader can fix the issue where if the clipped region of the image overlaps a button, that button will NOT work

like this:
GeometryReader { geo in
   Image("large")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
    .border(Color.black)
 }.frame(width: 150, height: hh)
```